# How do I do a method call every x seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

Is there a simple library that will allow me to do schedule a very simple task every x seconds specified by the web request coming in?

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
Something.after(5) { call_method }
```

Very simple. Do I have to install a library like resque, or is there a library that can handle this? I am not looking for full blown background queue processing, just a simple method call after x amount of seconds. I know about resque and sidekiq...

I need to run this from Rails or Sinatra.

Comment: Describe what you mean by "specified by the web request coming in". Allowing an incoming web-request to automatically trigger a job that reoccurs every X seconds is a good way to allow someone to DOS your system, rapidly making it unavailable and unusable. Do you have protection against that? Setting up a thread that runs on intervals wouldn't be hard. Avoiding false/repeated requests is harder.

Comment: Perhaps the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem is what you're looking for? Not sure if you count that as a 'full-blown background queue processing' or not (probably do).

Comment: Additionally to the other comments, if you are hosting the application on a service such as Heroku, you'll have to take into account what restrictions they have for such cases. In the specific case of Heroku, you'll have to use Delayed Job (DJ) for that, AFAIK.

Comment: @theTinMan the web request specifies the wait time. Don't need to worry about DOS because I am working on a prototype so that's why I was a simple quick solution.

Comment: @fmendez deploying on my own linux box. it's just a prototype at this point.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe rewrite your code sample:

```rb
Something.after(5) { call_method }
```

to:

```rb
Something
Thread.new do
  sleep(5)
  call_method
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to ship this out to a background task, take a look at [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) & [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). There is also a good [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) which is worth checking out. Anything else like using crons would not be right.

I did find this gem ([sucker_punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch)) which looks like it would do what you require